# IIS registered mime types

Tags: iis-7, web-config, mime-types, iis-8, web.config-transform

I have and web application that need some mime types registered on web.config:

Like theses:

> ```
> <staticContent>
>   <mimeMap fileExtension=".appcache" mimeType="text/cache-manifest" />
>   <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
>   <mimeMap fileExtension=".pkg" mimeType="application/x-newton-compatible-pkg" />
>   <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff"/>
>
> </staticContent>
> ```

When a run the app on IIS 7, all work correctly. but under IIS 8 (windows 10 pc), I should have to modify the web.config like this:

> ```
> <staticContent>
>   <!--mimeMap fileExtension=".appcache" mimeType="text/cache-manifest" /-->
>   <!--mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" /-->
>   <mimeMap fileExtension=".pkg" mimeType="application/x-newton-compatible-pkg" />
>   <!--mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff"/-->
>     <!-- This must be enabled in some environments -->
> </staticContent>
> ```

I know that on new IIS versions some mime types are registered as default, when I try to register its on my web.config some conflicts are generated with that mime types.

How I can, Automatically, detect if IIS have theses mime types or not, and modify my web.config automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web.config, always remove those MIME types first and then add them. Then your file works in all cases.